# Run PHP4 on Wamp5

Tags: wamp, php4

how to install php4 on wamp5 1.7.4, any ideas?

BTW, I know how to install php4 addon on WampServer 2.

Comment: You're no doubt aware, but the last release of PHP 4 was in August 2008, so I presume this is for the purposes of curiousity. (I'd certainly recommend upgrading any production server to the 5.x tree.)

Comment: I would echo @middaparka's comment, and also add that PHP4 has a large number of known and serious security issues, and these won't get fixed because it hasn't been supported for a long time. If you run PHP4 in a production system, you are asking to be hacked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only component of WAMP that uses PHP is Apache. Hence it is a standard installation procedure, same as any Apache on Windows. Nearly the same on all os.

1. Download PHP4 for Windows.
2. Install or Unzip PHP-files in a PHP-folder like c:\php.
3. Stop Apache.
4. Edit Apache:

```
  Replace PHP5 with PHP4:

  # PHP5
  #LoadModule php5_module "c:/phpdir/php5apache2_2.dll"
  #PHPIniDir "C:/phpdir/php-5.2.3-Win32"

  # PHP4
  LoadModule php4_module "C:/phpdir/php4apache2.dll"
  PHPIniDir "C:/phpdir"
```

1. Make sure you change "C:/phpdir" to wherever you put PHP 4.
2. Start Apache.

Comment: It does not work since there is no php4apache2.dll in phpdir.

Answer (score 4):

I installed php4 and php5 in my computer. I want to share the way, how to do this:

1. Download WampServer version WampServer2.0a.exe at: http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/WampServer%202.0/
2. Download plugin for Apache is version WampServer2-APACHE2058 and Download plugin for PHP is version WampServer2-PHP448 at: http://www.wampserver.com/en/

After download finish, install all plugin and run wampserver. 
To run php4, 
right mouse click on

> wampserver icon => select Apache  => Version => Select 2.0.58.

Then

> => select PHP => Version => select 4.4.8

Good luck

Comment: You save me, thx a lot. For guys, search the specific version keywords